# Find duplicates in a list of strings differing only in upper and lower case writing

Tags: python, list, duplicates

I have a list of strings that contains *'literal duplicates'* and *'pseudo-duplicates'* which differ only in lower- and uppercase writing. I am looking for a function that treats all literal duplicates as one group, returns their indices, and finds all pseudo-duplicates for these elements, again returning their indices.

Here's an example list:

`a = ['bar','bar','foo','Bar','Foo','Foo']`

And this is the output I am looking for (a list of lists of lists):

`dupe_list = [[[0,1],[3]],[[2],[4,5]]]`

Explanation: `'bar'` appears twice at the indexes 0 and 1 and there is one pseudo-duplicate `'Bar'` at index 3. `'foo'` appears once at index 2 and there are two pseudo-duplicates `'Foo'` at indexes 4 and 5.

Comment: is `bAr` or `bAR` or `fOo` a possibility?

Comment: Yes, it's only important that the characters themselves are equal, but differ only with regards to lower- or uppercase writing in one or multiple locations. It does not necessarily have to be the beginning of the string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one solution (you didn't clarify what the logic of list items will be and i considered that you want the items in lower format as they are met from left to right in the list, let me know if it must be different):

```
d={i:[[], []] for i in set(k.lower() for k in a)}

for i in range(len(a)):
    if a[i] in d.keys():
        d[a[i]][0].append(i)
    else:
        d[a[i].lower()][1].append(i)

result=list(d.values())
```

Output:

```
>>> print(result)

[[[0, 1], [3]], [[2], [4, 5]]]
```

Comment: you dont have to do a `set` for that genex, you can iterate directly

Comment: Looks good to me! Your solution also takes care of what @python_user mentioned in the comments ('FoO' is a pseudo-duplicate of 'foo'). I don't really understand your question, what do you mean by logic of list items?  Do you mean something like that there is some sort of order in the list? If you mean that, no, the function should also work if the strings in my question would be shuffled randomly. Let me know if this was your question.

Comment: I mean what will represent the items of the result-list? will they represent the unique words in lowercase  ('bar', 'foo') as they are met from left to right in the original list? If yes, then my solution will work ok. However logic could be different, eg you could want to represent the first variance of the word in the list (eg it could be 'Bar', 'foO'). For example ['Bar', 'bar', 'bar'] will result to [[2,3], [1]] in first scenario but to  [[1], [2,3]] in second scenario

Comment: More simply what will be the CORE word (that will be represented in the left item of the result-list)? Is it the word in lowercase, or the first variance of the word met in the list?

Comment: Ah okay, now I get it. No, it's not important that there is some sort of order in the result list, so your current solution works (for me at least! ). However, it would certainly nice to have this as an add-on. Feel free to add this functionality to your solution, I think it could be be helpful for others.

Comment: For example, I guess it could make sense to enforce that the indexes of exact duplicate are always in the first list and that the list of pseudo-duplicates (or 'variances' as you call them) of these are always in the second. But it geht's tricky if there is only one string and only one pseudo-duplicate of that string. In this case I there is no straightforward rule I guess, because there is no way go tell which string goes in the first list and which goes in the second.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I would achieve it. But you should consider using a dictionary and not a list of list of list. Dictionaries are excellent data structures for problems like this.

```
#default argument vars
a = ['bar','bar','foo','Bar','Foo','Foo']

#initalize a dictionary to count occurances
a_dict = {}
for i in a:
    a_dict[i] = None

#loop through keys in dictionary, which is values from a_list
    #loop through the items from list a
    #if the item is exact match to key, add index to list of exacts
    #if the item is similar match to key, add index to list of similars
#update the dictionary key's value 
for k, v in a_dict.items():
    index_exact = []
    index_similar = []
    for i in range(len(a)):
        print(a[i])
        print(a[i] == k)
        if a[i] == str(k):
            index_exact.append(i)
        elif a[i].lower() == str(k):
            index_similar.append(i) 
    a_dict[k] = [index_exact, index_similar]

#print out dictionary values to assure answer
print(a_dict.items())

#segregate values from dictionary to its own list.
dup_list = []
for v in a_dict.values():
    dup_list.append(v)
print(dup_list)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution. I have handled the situation where if there are only pseudo duplicates present or only literal duplicates present

```
a = ['bar', 'bar', 'foo', 'Bar', 'Foo', 'Foo', 'ka']
# Dictionaries to store the positions of words 
literal_duplicates = dict()
pseudo_duplicates = dict()

for index, item in enumerate(a):
    # Treates words as literal duplicates if word is in smaller case
    if item.islower():
        if item in literal_duplicates:
            literal_duplicates[item].append(index)
        else:
            literal_duplicates[item] = [index]
            # Handle if only literal_duplicates present             
            if item not in pseudo_duplicates:
                pseudo_duplicates[item] = []

    # Treates words as pseudo duplicates if word is in not in smaller case
    else:
        item_lower = item.lower()
        if item_lower in pseudo_duplicates:
            pseudo_duplicates[item_lower].append(index)
        else:
            pseudo_duplicates[item_lower] = [index]
            # Handle if only pseudo_duplicates present
            if item not in literal_duplicates:
                literal_duplicates[item_lower] = []

# Form final list from the dictionaries
dupe_list = [[v, pseudo_duplicates[k]] for k, v in literal_duplicates.items()]
```

Comment: The possible out for the example `a = ['bar','bar','foo','Bar','Foo','Foo', 'bAr', 'baR', 'FOo', 'Caa', 'ddd']`  would be `[[[0, 1], [3, 6, 7]], [[2], [4, 5, 8]], [[], [9]], [[10], []]]`

Answer (score 0):

Here is the simple and easy to understand answer for you

```
a = ['bar','bar','foo','Bar','Foo','Foo']
dupe_list = []
ilist = []
ilist2 =[]
samecase = -1
dupecase = -1
for i in range(len(a)):
    if a[i] != 'Null':
        ilist = []
        ilist2 = []
        for j in range(i+1,len(a)):
            samecase = -1
            dupecase = -1
            # print(a)
            if i not in ilist:
                ilist.append(i)
            if a[i] == a[j]:
                # print(a[i],a[j])
                samecase = j
                a[j] = 'Null'
            elif a[i] == a[j].casefold():
                # print(a[i],a[j])
                dupecase = j
                a[j] = 'Null'
            # print(samecase)
            # print(ilist,ilist2)
            if samecase != -1:
                ilist.append(samecase)
            if dupecase != -1:
                ilist2.append(dupecase)
        dupe_list.append([ilist,ilist2])
        a[i]='Null'
print(dupe_list)
```